# Get Date on a JSON Object list on Android Studio

Tags: android, json, android-studio

I want to get a date for a operation on Android Studio, I'm using a Json object list to add data but the getDate method doesn't exist so how I can get a date from a database and display it? That's the constructor, the third attributte should be a Date one.

```
classroomList.add(new Classroom(
                obj.getInt("id"),
                obj.getString("name")


        ));
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: How does you JSON look like? Which JSON library are you using? What is obj (which class, where does is come from?

Comment: can you show your JSON data?

Comment: I'm following this tutorial, https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-mysql-tutorial-to-perform-basic-crud-operation/#Custom-Adapter-Class